# Javascript - How to combine all combinations into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
[{
  name: 'foo',
  values: '10,12'
},
{
  name: 'bar',
  values: 'red,blue'
}]
```

Using some javascript logic I would like to output the following array:

```
[{
  option1: 10,
  option2: 'red'
},
{
  option1: 10,
  option2: 'blue'
},
{
  option1: 12,
  option2: 'red'
},
{
  option1: 12,
  option2: 'blue'
}]
```

What is the best and correct way to achieve this using javascript?

Comment: How many items will you have in your main array? Are there any limitations on the number of items in `values`?

Comment: will probably have a maximum of 10 values. ie values: 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20 etc etc

Comment: I just noticed your result array as option1 as a number even though it's a string in the original. Was that intentional? Will it always be two objects, with the first being numbers and the second being strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your first array is named arr.

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'foo',
  values: '10,12'
},
{
  name: 'bar',
  values: 'red,blue'
}];    
var v1 = arr[0].values.split(',');
var v2 = arr[1].values.split(',');
var res = new Array();
for(i in v1){
    for(j in v2){
        res.push({'option1':v1[i],'option2':v2[j]});
    }
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that can handle an arbitrary number of objects.

```js
function valuesCrossProduct(input) {
  return input.flatMap((current, index, array) => {
    let result = [];  
    let values  = current.values.split(',');
    for (let v of values) {
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i <= index) {
          // Skip creating cross products with self (i.e. == index)
          // and with previously visited objects (i.e. < index).
          continue; 
        }
        let iValues = array[i].values.split(',');
        let currentKey = `option${index}`;
        let iKey = `option${i}`;
          for (let iv of iValues) {
          result.push({
            [currentKey]: v,
            [iKey]: iv,
          });
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  });
}

let twoElementArray = [{
  name: 'foo',
  values: '10,12'
},
{
  name: 'bar',
  values: 'red,blue',
}];

let threeElementArray = [{
  name: 'foo',
  values: '10,12'
},
{
  name: 'bar',
  values: 'red,blue',
},
{
  name: 'baz',
  values: 'wham,bam',
}];

console.log(valuesCrossProduct(twoElementArray));
console.log(valuesCrossProduct(threeElementArray));
```

Comment: would it be possible to do this with 3 options .ie (red, blue, green)? also if we decide to leave green out, the output would be { option1:, 'red', option2: 'blue', option3: null }

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Would "red, blue, green" be the `values` property of a single input object? If so, what are the rules to define how to populate the `option<x>` entries in the result?

Answer (score 0):

Functional for the win.

Note: as it is, this only works for an array of two objects, with any number of values in each, where the first set of values are numbers and the second set are strings, which is what you described above.

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'foo',
  values: '10,12'
},
{
  name: 'bar',
  values: 'red,blue'
}];

const values = arr
  .map(o => o.values.split(','))
  .reduce((cur, next) => {
    return cur.map(c => {
      return next.map(n => {
        return {
          option1: parseInt(c),
          option2: n
        };
      });
    }).flat();
  });
  
console.log(values);
```

Comment: How can i alter the above if i wanted to add a 3rd array to the mix which will populate option3 ?

Comment: that depends on the expected result. Are you looking for every possible combination of every item in each array?

Answer (score 0):

If you need generic approach to get possible options from various values.

```js
const options = data => {
  let sets = [[]];
  data.forEach(({ values }, i) => {
    const new_set = [];
    values.split(",").forEach(value => {
      new_set.push(
        Array.from(sets, set => [...set, [`option${i + 1}`, value]])
      );
    });
    sets = new_set.flatMap(set => set);
  });

  return sets.map(set => Object.fromEntries(set));
};

const data = [
  {
    name: "foo",
    values: "10,12"
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    values: "red,blue,green"
  },
  {
    name: "test",
    values: "top,bottom"
  }
];

console.log(options(data));
```